# Compare 2 LISTBOX'es

Tags: delphi

I run D7 Enterprise on a Win 64  sp2.

IN my program I have 2 Listboxes (lb1, Lb2) .

Lb1 may contain up to 35.000 items. (string[4] )
Lb2 may contain up to 35.000 items. (string[4] )

Both listboxes are SORTED.

Thera may be duplicated items (from 0 to 30.000 ) in the listboxes, and I want to locate these duplicates.

I have tried the "bottom-up" type (eg: get element from bottom of listbox2 , scan through listbox1 to bottom, mark equal elements, (eventually copy to a third Listbox), take next element i Listbox2 do sacn i lisbox1 again and continue till top af listbox2. )

This method is INDEED working, but it is tedious and extremely slow (takes approx. 8 minutes (+/-) / 35000 item LB1 / 25000 items LB2).

I wonder if It is possible to modify a TStringList Component:    TStringList.NoDuplicates;  to
TStringList.getDuplicates; or something like,  and if so how do I do it ??

Or have I not found a "hidden" (at least for me ) possibility / method  in the TStringList component?

Or is ther a third way to find the duplicates ?

Please help.

Thanks

KRIS

Comment: So you want to find the *intersection* of the two list boxes, that is, the strings that are present in both list boxes?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand :    YES

Comment: Instead of doing a linear search in the second list box, do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). That reduces the complexity from O(n) to O(log n). Or you can use a dictionary to get O(1).

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand   - Could be a good idea.  And I feel, that this (new) method may be teh best one.   (and by the way I do regret all the TYPOS in the text in my question, - I have a DELL lbtop with an extremely sensitive keyboard.  and my control-reading failed compe´letely.)  I will try this and ask again, if any problems should occur.   THANKS angain.

Comment: @KristianSander Accessing an item in a listbox involves sending two messages to the underlying Windows API listbox. This is probably a relatively slow process (Actually I suspect it). Maybe getting all the strings out of the listboxes into string arrays and then do the job on those arrays is maybe faster. To be tested!

Comment: @fpiette is right. Just copy them to two local `TStringList` variables: `A := TStringList.Create; A.Assign(ListBox1.Items); B := TStringList.Create; B.Assign(ListBox2.Items)` (with proper `try..finally` blocks, of course). Then do all the work on `A` and `B`.

Comment: Have you looked into the .Duplicates property? http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStringList_Duplicates.html

Comment: HI Thanks again.   I will look deeper into the TStringList - posibilites....  Anyway I did changed the SEARCH/COMPARE function to a BINARY-SEARCH/COMPARE function. After the obligate FAULT-correction (typos mostly)  I did at WORST-CASe test. 64K items il LB1 , 62K ITEM IN lb2.   (estimated 10 minutes befor / orignal search/replace func. )  . Now oNLY 17 (seventeen)  seconds including LISTBOX updates. Certainly an improvement.  A million thanks again to  Andreas Rejbrand for the idea.

Comment: I think that the best advice for you is to view visual controls as things that display the underlying data. They are purely for display, and to allow the user to indicate choices. Algorithmic code should never be implemented with visual controls.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good idea to do as if you were doing it by hand, following each list down with your finger.

Here is a procedure to do that.

```
procedure TFormTest.CompareLists(const Lista, Listb, Listc: TStrings);
var
  a, b, amax, bmax : integer;
begin
  aMax := Lista.Count;
  bMax := Listb.Count;

  Listc.Clear;

  a:=0;
  b:=0;

  while (a< aMax) and (b<bMax) do
  begin
    // Once either index goes past end of list we are done;
    case Sign( CompareStr( Lista[a], Listb[b])) of  // oer CompareText if not case sensitive
      -1:
      begin
        // ista[a] < List0[ b ]b
        inc( a );
      end;
      0:
      begin
        // a = b
        Listc.add( Lista[a] );  // same so could be either
        inc(a);
        inc(b);
      end;
      1:
      begin
        inc( b );
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

You can copy that straight into your program.

It also makes it easy to compare whether copying to external lists is worth while. I did that and fount that using list box entries takes about 4 seconds for 35000 is entries (many longer that 4 characters) and less than a second for separate lists. That difference far exceeds the time taken to copy the items to separate string lists, but both times are way better what you achieved.

Here is the full test unit:

```
unit UnitTest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.Math, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TFormTest = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    ListBox2: TListBox;
    ListBox3: TListBox;
    EditCompareLists: TEdit;
    EditCompareListBoxes: TEdit;
    ButtonTest: TButton;
    EditCount1: TEdit;
    EditCount2: TEdit;
    EditCount3: TEdit;
    procedure ButtonTestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure CompareLists( const Lista, Listb, Listc : TStrings );
  end;

var
  FormTest: TFormTest;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TFormTest.ButtonTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  List1, List2, List3 : TStringList;
  iTime : TTime;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // 1. Generate lists - should be string[4] but if bigger should slow things down
  List1 := TStringList.Create;
  Try
    List2 := TStringList.Create;
    try
      List3 := TStringList.Create;
      try
        List1.Sorted := TRUE;
        List2.Sorted := TRUE;
        List1.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
        List2.Duplicates := dupIgnore;

        for i := 1 to 50000 do
        begin
          List1.Add( IntToStr( Random( 65000 )));
          List2.Add( IntToStr( Random( 65000 )));
        end;

        ListBox1.Items.Assign( List1 );
        ListBox2.Items.Assign( List2 );

        EditCount1.Text := IntToStr(ListBox1.Items.Count );
        EditCount2.Text := IntToStr(ListBox2.Items.Count );
        // now see how fast eachcan be sorted
        // first - list boxes
        iTime := Now;
        CompareLists( ListBox1.Items, ListBox2.Items, ListBox3.Items );
        iTime := Now - iTime;
        EditCompareListBoxes.Text := TimeToStr( iTime );
        EditCount3.Text := IntToStr(ListBox3.Items.Count );

        // and Lists
        iTime := Now;
        CompareLists( List1, List2, List3 );
        iTime := Now - iTime;
        EditCompareLists.Text := TimeToStr( iTime );
      finally
        List3.Free;
      end;
    finally
      List2.Free;
    end;
  Finally
    List1.Free;
  End;
end;

procedure TFormTest.CompareLists(const Lista, Listb, Listc: TStrings);
var
  a, b, amax, bmax : integer;
begin
  aMax := Lista.Count;
  bMax := Listb.Count;

  Listc.Clear;

  a:=0;
  b:=0;

  while (a< aMax) and (b<bMax) do
  begin
    // Once either index goes past end of list we are done;
    case Sign( CompareStr( Lista[a], Listb[b])) of  // oer CompareText if not case sensitive
      -1:
      begin
        // ista[a] < List0[ b ]b
        inc( a );
      end;
      0:
      begin
        // a = b
        Listc.add( Lista[a] );  // same so could be either
        inc(a);
        inc(b);
      end;
      1:
      begin
        inc( b );
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I will study it in depth, and (if necessary) modify it to suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two sorted lists you can compare the first entries then advance one or both lists based on that comparison:

- equal : duplicate, advance to next on both lists
- first > than second, advance to next on 2nd list
- second > first, advance to the next on 1st list
- one or both lists end : done

As others have mentioned comparing the data inside list controls will be much slower then between string lists or arrays.